# The little search thing wont work anymore

Tags: unity, lenses, scopes

I never had a problem with this before but today when I tried to use that app, the one that says "Search your computer and online sources" when you hover over it, it wont find ANYTHING useful. It wont find stuff I know I have on my computer (like files or programs) but it keeps finding crap I don't think I even have on my computer and has nothing to do with what I typed in to search.

I get "Ask Ubuntu" but other than that, even if I search something that I KNOW it has found in the past, it just returns useless reference crap and A LOT junk that doesn't have much to do with what I was looking for. How do I make it search properly again?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the "little search thing" or be more descriptive?

Answer (score 1):

Open the dash and click "Filter results". Make sure that things you want to search for are checked. Then make sure that you are on the *home* lens.

[image]

You might also want to disable online results. Open System Settings -> Security and Privacy -> Search.

[image]

That should solve your problem.